# onCreate(Unknown Source) for Application class with Proguard (only happens on Samsung devices)

Tags: android, proguard, samsung-mobile

I've been testing my app on Sony and Nexus devices as well as multiple emulators (API 10 - 19) for several weeks and things seem fine, however, two of my testers (who live remotely) are experiencing crashes during startup and ACRA isn't offering the option to send a crash log email, which leads me to believe it's a crash before ACRA is even instantiated. ACRA works as expected on my devices and emulators and offers to send an email (via default app).

Are Samsung phones doing some special initialization? Am I doing anything in the following code which could cause a crash?

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
        mailTo = "crash@mydomain.com",
        customReportContent = {
                ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
                ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
                ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
                ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
                ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA,
                ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
                ReportField.LOGCAT }
)
public class AppState extends Application {

    private static final String DIRECTORY_ROOT = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    private static final String DIRECTORY_PICTURES_APP = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyApp";

    private static final LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppState.class);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ACRA.init(this);

        // try to create log file and directory; if successful, configure ACRA to include last lines with crash report
        if (createLogFile()) {
            ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getConfig();
            config.setApplicationLogFile(LOGGER_FILENAME);
            ACRA.setConfig(config);
        }

        ...log4j, database init, etc...
```

The source for the project is [located here on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/dumpsterdiver/code/).

**EDIT #1:**

Finally got one of the Samsung Remote Test Lab devices working! Screen still isn't visible, but I can at least see logcat. Here is the reason for the crash:

`ERROR  AndroidRuntime  at org.dumpsterdiver.sync.AppState.onCreate(Unknown Source)`

So that means the system is unable to find my Application class? After a bit of Googling similar problems, I think it might be a proguard error (sigh, again), so I've been playing with various suggestions from other answers. None of these have helped so far (still experimenting with various values):

```
-keep public class org.dumpsterdiver.sync.AppState
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
```

**EDIT #2:**

Adding this line to my proguard config file seems to fix the problem:

```
-keep class * { *; }
```

But my APK is 500 KB larger (3.7 -> 4.2 MB) and I suspect this probably defeats half the point of using proguard in the first place? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Have your testers install adb, enable USB logging and capture the logcat. Better yet, get a device. Should be faster.

Comment: One of my testers is living in a village and barely has internet access (my 4MB app needs about an hour to download) and does not have access to a computer. The other is in a similar situation and neither are very technically savvy. I would get another device but I just bought a new tablet and phone (2 different companies) for testing and now I'm in the red. I'm shopping around to see if i can find some used devices because Samsung is asking $650 to get a Samsung S4 developers edition. btw this is an open-source project from which I will be making no money.

Comment: If it's open source, then provide a link to the source and invite other developers to help you.

Comment: Ok link added but who are these "other developers" that you speak of? I've open sourced a number of projects on a number of sites in the last 10 years and I have yet to be offered help from the outside.

Comment: I'm away from my home office this weekend, but I have a half dozen Samsung devices -- even a couple of pre-lease models -- and will see if I can check this on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, this line was the problem:

```
-keep public class org.dumpsterdiver.sync.AppState
```

Changing it to this seems to have done the trick:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

Comment: You have enough points, you could try re-opening this question with a lot of bounty and hope it's enough. Otherwise try adding more of these "-keep public class" lines for the class which is causing you problems.